# Way to retrieve local variables when calling checked and onchange event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application. Please bear with me.

I am creating a react table with checkboxes on each row. I want to know which row is selected by adding onchange and checked events in the checkbox. But upon checking in the debug, seems it cannot see which rows are checked.

The local variables this, modifiedMap and row are undefined.

This is the code I have

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useTableState } from "react-table";
import Table from "../TransactionPanelTable";

const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

  const filtersArr = Object.entries(filters);

  // Get our base data
  let rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rows.push({
      transaction_seq: 1234,
      rec_count: 1234,
      user_id: "test",
      updated_at: "",
      duration: 1.23
    });
  }

  // Apply Filters
  if (filtersArr.length) {
    rows = rows.filter(row =>
      filtersArr.every(([key, value]) => row[key].includes(value))
    );
  }

  // Apply Sorting
  if (sortBy.length) {
    const [{ id, desc }] = sortBy;
    rows = [...rows].sort(
      (a, b) => (a[id] > b[id] ? 1 : a[id] === b[id] ? 0 : -1) * (desc ? -1 : 1)
    );
  }

  // Get page counts
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(rows.length / pageSize);
  const rowStart = pageSize * pageIndex;
  const rowEnd = rowStart + pageSize;

  // Get the current page
  rows = rows.slice(rowStart, rowEnd);

  return {
    rows,
    pageCount
  };
};

export default function({ infinite }) {
  const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map());
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const currentRequestRef = useRef();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    // We can use a ref to disregard any outdated requests
    const id = Date.now();
    currentRequestRef.current = id;

    // Call our server for the data
    const { rows, pageCount } = await getServerData({
      filters,
      sortBy,
      pageSize,
      pageIndex
    });

    let newMap = new Map();
    rows.forEach(row => newMap.set(row, false));
    setCheckedMap(newMap);

    // If this is an outdated request, disregard the results
    if (currentRequestRef.current !== id) {
      return;
    }

    // Set the data and pageCount
    setData(rows);
    setState(old => ({
      ...old,
      pageCount
    }));

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const handleCheckedChange = row => {
    let modifiedMap = checkedMap;
    modifiedMap.set(row, !checkedMap.get(row));
    setCheckedMap(modifiedMap);
    console.log(checkedMap);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Transaction(s)",
      className: "left",
      columns: [
        {
          id: "checkbox",
          accessor: "checkbox",
          key: "transaction_seq",
          Cell: ({ original }) => {
            return (
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                checked={checkedMap.get(original)}
                onChange={() => handleCheckedChange(original)}
              />
            );
          },

          sortable: false,
          width: 45
        },
        {
          Header: "Transaction Seq",
          accessor: "transaction_seq",
          id: "transaction_seq",
          minWidth: 200,
          maxWidth: 300
        },
        {
          Header: "Record count",
          // accessor: d => d.lastName,
          minWidth: 140,
          maxWidth: 200,
          aggregate: "average"
        },
        {
          Header: "User Id",
          accessor: "user_id",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          Header: "Updated At",
          accessor: "updatedAt",
          width: 200
        },
        {
          Header: "Duration",
          accessor: "duration",
          aggregate: "average",
          minWidth: 100,
          Cell: row => (
            <div
              style={{
                width: `${row.value}%`,
                minWidth: "5px",
                height: "20px",
                backgroundColor: `hsla(${row.value}, 100%, 45%, 1)`,
                borderRadius: "2px",
                transition: "all .4s ease"
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  // Make a new controllable table state instance
  const state = useTableState({ pageCount: 0 });

  const [{ sortBy, filters, pageIndex, pageSize }, setState] = state;

  // When sorting, filters, pageSize, or pageIndex change, fetch new data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [sortBy, filters, pageIndex, pageSize]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table
        {...{
          data,
          checkedMap,
          columns,
          infinite,
          state, // Pass the state to the table
          loading,
          manualSorting: true, // Manual sorting
          manualFilters: true, // Manual filters
          manualPagination: true, // Manual pagination
          disableMultiSort: true, // Disable multi-sort
          disableGrouping: true, // Disable grouping
          debug: true
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Thank you for your help

Edit: this is for the table component

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import {
  useTable,
  useColumns,
  useRows,
  useFilters,
  useSortBy,
  useExpanded,
  usePagination,
  useFlexLayout
} from "react-table";

const Table = styled.div`
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  overflow-x: auto;
`;

const RowBase = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;

  :last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
`;

const Row = styled(RowBase)`
  ${props =>
    props.even &&
    css`
      background: rgba(42, 117, 146, 0.12);
    `}
`;

const HeaderRow = styled(RowBase)`
  background: rgba(42, 117, 146, 1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
`;

const Pagination = styled(RowBase)`
  background: rgba(42, 117, 146, 1);
  color: white;
`;

const Cell = styled.div`
  border-right: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.6rem;

  :last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
`;

const Header = styled(Cell)`
  font-weight: bold;

  ${props => {
    const width = (props.sortedIndex + 1) * 5;
    return (
      props.sorted &&
      (props.sortedDesc
        ? css`
            box-shadow: inset 0 ${width}px hsla(0, 100%, 40%);
          `
        : css`
            box-shadow: inset 0 -${width}px hsl(55, 100%, 50%);
          `)
    );
  }};
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.7rem;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;

  :disabled {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
`;

const Select = styled.select`
  appearance: none;
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.7rem;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.7rem;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 100%;
`;

const useInfiniteScroll = ({
  enabled,
  sortBy,
  filters,
  pageIndex,
  pageSize
}) => {
  const listRef = useRef();
  const [scrollToIndex, setScrollToIndex] = useState(0);
  const [rowHeight, setRowHeight] = useState(40);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(500);
  const [overscan, setOverscan] = useState(25);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!enabled) {
      return;
    }
    if (listRef.current) {
      listRef.current.scrollToItem(scrollToIndex, "start");
    }
  }, [scrollToIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!enabled) {
      return;
    }
    if (listRef.current) {
      listRef.current.scrollToItem(0, "start");
    }
  }, [sortBy, filters]);

  return {
    listRef,
    scrollToIndex,
    setScrollToIndex,
    rowHeight,
    setRowHeight,
    height,
    setHeight,
    overscan,
    setOverscan
  };
};

export default function MyTable({ loading, infinite, ...props }) {
  const instance = useTable(
    {
      ...props
    },
    useColumns,
    useRows,
    useFilters,
    useSortBy,
    useExpanded,
    usePagination,
    useFlexLayout
  );

  const {
    getTableProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    getRowProps,
    pageOptions,
    page,
    state: [{ pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy, filters }],
    gotoPage,
    prepareRow,
    previousPage,
    nextPage,
    setPageSize,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage
  } = instance;

  const { listRef, rowHeight, height, overscan } = useInfiniteScroll({
    enabled: infinite,
    sortBy,
    filters,
    pageIndex,
    pageSize
  });

  let tableBody;

  const renderRow = (row, index, style = {}) => {
    if (!row) {
      return (
        <Row {...{ style, even: index % 2 }}>
          <Cell>Loading more...</Cell>
        </Row>
      );
    }
    prepareRow(row);
    return (
      <Row {...row.getRowProps({ style, even: index % 2 })}>
        {row.cells.map(cell => {
          const isPivot = row.groupByID === cell.column.id;
          const showAggregate = row.subRows && !isPivot;
          return (
            <Cell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
              {showAggregate ? (
                cell.column.aggregate ? (
                  cell.render("Aggregated")
                ) : null
              ) : (
                <span>
                  {isPivot ? (
                    <span
                      style={{
                        cursor: "pointer",
                        paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
                        paddingRight: "1rem",
                        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
                      }}
                      onClick={() => row.toggleExpanded()}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                  {cell.render("Cell")}
                  {isPivot ? <span> ({row.subRows.length})</span> : null}
                </span>
              )}
            </Cell>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    );
  };

  if (infinite) {
    tableBody = (
      <List
        ref={listRef}
        height={height}
        itemCount={rows.length + 1}
        itemSize={rowHeight}
        overscanCount={overscan}
        scrollToAlignment="start"
        {...getRowProps()}
      >
        {({ index, style }) => {
          const row = rows[index];
          return renderRow(row, index, style);
        }}
      </List>
    );
  } else {
    tableBody =
      page && page.length ? page.map((row, i) => renderRow(row, i)) : null;
  }

  let pagination;

  pagination = pageOptions.length ? (
    <Pagination {...getRowProps()}>
      <Cell>
        <Button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          Previous
        </Button>{" "}
        <Button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          Next
        </Button>{" "}
        <span>
          Page{" "}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{" "}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{" "}
          <Input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
              gotoPage(page);
            }}
            style={{ width: "100px" }}
          />
        </span>{" "}
        <Select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>{" "}
        <Button onClick={() => reprocessConfirmation()}>Reprocess</Button>
      </Cell>
    </Pagination>
  ) : null;

  function reprocessConfirmation() {
    let confirmation = window.confirm("Do you want to reprocess transaction");
    if (confirmation === true) console.log("OK");
    else console.log("CANCEL");
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table {...getTableProps()}>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <HeaderRow {...headerGroup.getRowProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <Header
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                sorted={column.sorted}
                sortedDesc={column.sortedDesc}
                sortedIndex={column.sortedIndex}
              >
                <div>
                  <span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </span>{" "}
                </div>
                {column.canFilter ? <div>{column.render("Filter")}</div> : null}
              </Header>
            ))}
          </HeaderRow>
        ))}
        {tableBody}
        <Row {...getRowProps()}>
          {loading ? (
            <Cell>
              <strong>Loading...</strong>
            </Cell>
          ) : (
            <Cell>{rows.length} Total Records</Cell>
          )}
        </Row>
        {pagination}
      </Table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code for your Table component as well?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I already added table component. I cannot get the value of the selected row and retrieve the key/value into console for verification

Comment: import { useTableState } from "react-table". i'm trying to test your code right now. This does not seem like a named export from react-table. Got any updates?

Comment: I added the complete imports from the table component. I tried to debug from the checkbox events (handleCheckedChange) , still no luck, the row is undefined